# how to clear textbox value on other textbox focus in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to clear a `2nd textbox value` when i'm doing `focus (or changing value)` of `1st textbox` using `jquery` ?

I'm trying to use

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
validateFocus();
});

function validateFocus() {
    $('#1stTextBox').focus(function () {
        $('2nsTextBox').val('');
    });
}
```

not working for me help me to correct me thanks

Comment: `#txtDate` and `txtDate` maybe? `$("#txtDate").val()`

Comment: Post your checkDate() function code and better to put your code in fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#txt1').focus(function() {

  $('#txt2').attr('value','');
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!checkDate($("#txtDate").val()))
          {

            $("#txtDate").val("");
            $('#txtDate').focus();
           }
```

you forgot # on this  $("txtDate").val()

Answer (score 0):

The question is quiet unclear..
If you want to clear another textbox, you can simply call it as you did for the txtDate;

```
if(!checkDate($("#txtDate").val()))
{

$("#txtDate").val("");
$('#txtDate').focus();

$("#Your2ndTextBox").val("");
}
```

This should be enough..

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
$(input[id$='firsttextboxid']).focus(function() {
  $("#secondtextboxid").val('');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this demo :

[jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/V25g5/4/][1]

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the selector here `$('2nsTextBox').val('');`

```
function validateFocus() {
    $('#1stTextBox').focus(function () {
        $('#2nsTextBox').val('');// may be # if its id, no need to tell u other selectors by seeing ur rep
    });
}
```